# How can I pass Magento customer authorization token from php curl to the browser?

Tags: api, rest, integration, magento2

I am trying to integrate a new website(Wordpress website) with a Magento website, I've made the API integration using php curl, I've also add the Magento website url to the new website.

I can create account and authenticate the users through the Magento API but this is limited to the API features only, the problem now is I don't know how can I let the user login through the new website(the Wordpress website) and when he/she visits the Magento website he doesn't have to login again. (A single sign on) between the two websites.

I've tried the following but can't figure out how to pass the users data to the browser so he doesn't have to login again in the Magento website.

```
   $curl = curl_init();

  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://<my_domain>/rest/V1/integration/customer/token',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('username' => '<my_username>','password' => '<my_password>'),
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
  ));
  
  $token = curl_exec($curl);
  
  echo ($token) . "<hr>";
  
  $curl = curl_init();

  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => '<my_domain>/rest/V1/customers/me',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      'Authorization: Bearer ' . json_decode($token),
    ),
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
  ));
  
  $response2 = curl_exec($curl);
  
  echo $response2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set basic authorization in cURL

$userName = ""User_Name"";
$password = ""User_Password"";

$this->curl->setCredentials($userName, $password);

Set cURL cookies using addCookie method:

$this->curl->addCookie(""cookie-name"", ""cookie-value"");

See detailed documentation at: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/gs-curl.html#set-basic-authorization-in-curl